# What is the highest number of consecutive matches lost by a football player?

Tags: football, records

Jack Grealish (Aston Villa) [lost his 20th consecutive game](https://www.goal.com/en/news/grealish-ends-record-barren-spell-as-villa-win-first-premier/1vhiipinu0fjf1mg01xh5675m4) in the Premier League.
So I wonder which players have done worse than that ?

Comment: Surely this has to be a player from [Fort William FC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/49186402) ;)

Comment: It's worth making the distinction between "most consecutive defeats in one competition" and "most consecutive defeats overall". Grealish's 20-game losing streak in the Premier League was interrupted by a three-year spell in the Championship, during which time he won quite a few games.

Answer (score -1):

Probably a player of Darwen 1898-1899 (2nd division). This team has the record of 18 consecutive defeats as mentioned in [the Wikipedia article about UK football records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football_records_and_statistics_in_England#Losses).

Comment: The question already pointed out a player who lost 20 consecutive games. How would a player have more straight losses than that (20) if their team only lost 18 straight games?

Comment: The question doesn't mentionned 20 games **What is the highest number of consecutive matches lost by a football player?**

Comment: It's the first of only two sentences. I'm not sure how you miss it.

Comment: Like @F1Krazy says, answer is not correct because _Grealish's 20-game losing streak in the Premier League was interrupted by a three-year spell in the Championship, during which time he won quite a few games_

Comment: This is exactly why I said that the distinction needed to be made. Regrettably, OP has not done that.